# PageHeader appearing when SubReport

Tags: .net, activereports, componentone

I am using ActiveReports 7

I have developed a report that has a SubReport in the group footer.  When the subreport is visible, the PageHeader disappears from the report, when the subreport is not visible, the page header is there.

Am I missing something that removed the pageheader when using subreports in AR7??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied the SP and this fixed the problem....go figure...

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't happen, but you'll need to give us a lot more information in order to answer properly. This is a question probably best answered by sending the reports to ComponentOne support via the ActiveReports Support Forum (click *Forums* from [the product page](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ActiveReports/)) so that the support team can review it and troubleshoot.

Some ideas to help you troubleshoot:

- Does the PageHeader display when the subreport is in the Detail section instead of the GroupFooter?
- Does it happen with any report being used as the subreport or only one?
- Is there code in the subreport or parent report? Try commenting out all code -*at least* all code that accesses the report, sections or controls on the report to see if there is some code impacting the behavior here.

Comment: Scott... Yo answer your questions, No, just this one, there is only a graph in the sub report, there is no otehr code that references the PageHeader anywhere in the report.

Comment: @larryr We'd need to be able to download the report definition files for the parent report and subreport (rpx) and see the code used in order to troubleshoot. It is probably best to use the Forums for AR (linked to above) or contact ComponentOne support. Please feel free to contact me directly if you don't get a satisfactory reply from C1 and I'll help you.